# Delegate between TableViewController and ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I'm in my first week of developing in iOS and have become stuck on an issue with passing data between view controllers. My set up consists of a view with VC having a button in it and also a container view (no associated view controller). The container view has an embedded Segue to a TableView with TableViewController. The table has 6 rows and each row has a stepper that can change the value of a text view on the associated row. What I would like to do is collect the values of all the textviews when I press the button on the main view.

I am trying to use delegate to do this but when I press the button the returned value is always nil. I believe the problem is to do with the fact the VC is not being passed to the table view controller via the prepareForSegue function but I'm not sure why? Could be to do with the load order of the controllers?

```
import UIKit

class PredictionViewController: UIViewController, PredictionDelegate {

    var predictionData: String!

    @IBOutlet weak var messageTextBox: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var predictionSubmitButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.messageTextBox.isEditable = false
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    }

    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "predictionSegue") {
            // pass data to next view
            let vc = segue.destination as! PredictionsTableViewController
            vc.predictionHomeDelegate = self
        }
    }

    func receiveData(with data: String) {
        predictionData = data
        print(predictionData)
    }

    @IBAction func predictionSubmitButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print(predictionData)
    }

}
```

TableViewController: (stripped to minimum)

```
import UIKit

protocol PredictionDelegate: class {
    func receiveData(with data: String)
}

class PredictionsTableViewController: UITableViewController, PredictionDelegate {

    weak var predictionHomeDelegate: PredictionDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var homeTeamScore1: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var homeTeamStepper1: UIStepper!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    }

    func getPredictionList() {
        //does some stuff
        self.passDataBackwards()
    }

    func receiveData(with data: String) {}

    func passDataBackwards() {
        let data = "{\"score\":\"1\"}"
        predictionHomeDelegate?.receiveData(with: data)
    }

    @IBAction func homeTeamStepper1Action(_ sender: UIStepper) {

        let score = Int(sender.value).description
        homeTeamScore1.text = score
        self.passDataBackwards()
    }
}
```

[image: storyboard view]

Any help gratefully received!

Comment: A little off topic but since it is your first week. Class names should always start with a capital letter. `PredictionsTableViewController` in your case. Functions and variables use `camelCase`

Comment: Thanks for that, will go through and update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

After comments...

You have the wrong idea about Protocols and Delegates. They are not needed here.

Instead, in your "home" VC, get a reference to the embedded VC. Then, add a function in your embedded VC that you can call to get its data.

[image]

```
// "home" view controller
class PredictionViewController: UIViewController {

    // this will be a reference to the embedded view controller
    var embeddedVC: PredictionsTableViewController?

    @IBAction func getDataButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if let tableData = embeddedVC?.getMyData() {
            print("Result: \(tableData)")
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "predictionSegue") {
            if let vc = segue.destination as? PredictionsTableViewController {
                // get a reference to the embedded VC
                self.embeddedVC = vc
            }
        }
    }

}

// embedded view controller
class PredictionsTableViewController: UIViewController {

    var numTaps = 0

    func getMyData() -> String {
        return "\(numTaps)"
    }

    @IBAction func didTap(_ sender: Any) {
        numTaps += 1
    }

}
```

<s>You're close, but a couple mistakes...</s>

Here is a very, very simple example. View controller with container, which has a view controller with a button.

Code:

```
import UIKit

// your protocol    
protocol PredictionDelegate: class {
    func receiveData(with data: String)
}

// embedded view controller
// NOTE: this should NOT include PredictionDelegate
class PredictionsTableViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var predictionHomeDelegate: PredictionDelegate?

    @IBAction func didTap(_ sender: Any) {
        // on button tap, "send data back"
        predictionHomeDelegate?.receiveData(with: "Test")
    }

}

// "home" view controller
// NOTE: this DOES include PredictionDelegate
class PredictionViewController: UIViewController, PredictionDelegate {

    func receiveData(with data: String) {
        print(data)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "predictionSegue") {
            if let vc = segue.destination as? PredictionsTableViewController {
                // set self as the delegate of the embedded PredictionsTableViewController
                vc.predictionHomeDelegate = self
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Notes:

- Do NOT include `func receiveData(with data: String) {}` in your embedded view controller
- Do NOT assign `PredictionDelegate` to your embedded view controller

Comment: Thanks @DonMag but the button isn't on the table view controller. I've updated my question with a storyboard image.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense.... Where is the button if it's not part of the table view controller?

Comment: The button is on the main view. The reason for doing this is because I would like the embedded tableView to be scrollable and have the button always visible, rather than needing to scroll to the bottom of the table to press submit.

Comment: Thanks @DonMag that's done the trick. For clarity the reason I don't need delegates here is because it's an embedded controller and therefore already accessible? Another VC that's perhaps a show rather than embed would require delegates? Thanks again.

Comment: No... Simply put - the Protocol / Delegate pattern is used when you want a "second" view controller (child / presented / pushed / etc) to be able to call a function inside the "first" view controller.

Comment: Right as opposed to mine being first calling one inside the second. Great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You  need to hook your segue to the vc itself instead of the cell and use

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "predictionSegue", sender: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks @Sh_Khan. Are you saying I don’t need the container view?

Comment: i don't care whether you insert the source VC to container or not , if you want **prepareForSegue** to be called then use **performSegue**

Answer (score 0):

Since these are two separate screens I am not too sure it makes too much sense to have the button on the first view controller that submits data from the second, can the button not just be on the second. If for whatever reason it can't you could pass the data back to the first view controller on segueing back by adding a public variable to the first view controller and adding another prepare method to the second to pass the data back like you have done when adding the delegate.

Comment: The reason for doing this is because I would like the embedded tableView to be scrollable and have the button always visible, rather than needing to scroll to the bottom of the table to press submit.

Your suggestion has gone a bit over my head. At the moment I have an embed segue to get the tableView on to the standard view. Can I segue backwards from an embed view and if so how? Thanks